# jenkins integration part..cant push feature to master to origin

Tags: git, jenkins, publisher

I receive the following error:

> ERROR: Failed to push branch master to origin
>   hudson.plugins.git.GitException:
>   Command "git push http://18.217.127.239:8080/gitbucket/git/sudheer/maven_web.git HEAD:master -f"
>   returned status code 128:
>   Build step 'Git Publisher' marked build as failure
>   Finished: FAILURE

What can I do?

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Please, consider updating your question to get better chances to be answered. In the current state people won't know what your issue is; you just posted the error with no explanation or whatsoever. Thanks.

Comment: is that git URL correct? Do other git commands succeed, e.g `git pull`?